# Convergnece for integral on a complex Hilbert

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-integration, absolute-convergence

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a complex Hilbert space. Let us consider the following integral:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathcal{H}}e^{-i\cdot f(x)} dx
\end{equation*}
Is there an upper bound of this integral (at least in the case $\mathcal{H}=\mathbb{R}^d$)? For which condition of $f(x)$?

Remark: actually I need the convergence to write the exponential function as series and swap it with the integral.

Comment: It is a vast difference if you integrate over *some Hilbert space* or $\mathbb{R}^d$, and you should tell us more about the function $f$ so that this question is not much too general. It would help a lot if you told us more about the context in which this question arises and what your thougts about it are!

Comment: And what "$dx$" means in a Hilbert space that isn't  finite dimensional.

Comment: @kimchilover I'm actually working on a Sobolev space: the Cameron-Martin Space of absolutely continuous function $x:[0,t] \to \mathbb{R}^d$, with square integrable weak derivative $\dot{x}$.

Comment: @Luke You're right, the $\mathbb{R}^d$ case it was just to understand how it could work. My interest is actually on a generic Hilbert space. I would define $f:\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{R}$ as $f(x)=\int_0^tF(x(s))\dot x(s)ds$, with $x \in \mathcal{H}$ and where each component of $F$ are transform of complex Borel measure.